# Delayed Job creating Airbrakes every time it raises an error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

```
def perform
  refund_log = {
    success: refund_retry.success?,
    amount: refund_amount,
    action: "refund"
  }
  if refund_retry.success?
    refund_log[:reference] = refund_retry.transaction.id
    refund_log[:message] = refund_retry.transaction.status
  else
    refund_log[:message] = refund_retry.message
    refund_log[:params] = {}
    refund_retry.errors.each do |error|
      refund_log[:params][error.code] = error.message
    end
    order_transaction.message = refund_log[:params].values.join('|')
    raise "delayed RefundJob has failed"
  end
end
```

When I raise "delayed RefundJob has failed" in the else statement, it creates an [Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/pages/home). I want to run the job again if it ends up in the else section.

Is there any way to re-queue the job without raising an exception? And prevent creating an airbrake?

I am using delayed_job version 1.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way would be to re-queue, i.e. create a new job and enqueue it, and then exit the method normally.

Comment: The problem with that is that the new job might end up in the else loop too (its like inception), which means that I would have to create a 3rd-level job, and so on

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Roman's response, you can create a new job, with a `retry` parameter in it, and enqueue it.

If you maintain the `retry` parameter (increment it each time you re-enqueue a job), you can track how many retries you made, and thus avoid an endless retry loop.

Answer (score 0):

DelayedJob expects a job to raise an error to requeued, by definition.

From there you can either :

- Ignore your execpetion on airbrake side, see https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake#filtering so it still gets queued again without filling your logs
- Dive into DelayedJob code where you can see on https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/job.rb#L65 that a method named **reschedule** is available and used by **run_with_lock** ( https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/job.rb#L99 ). From there you can call reschedule it manually, instead of raising your exception.

About the later solution, I advise adding some mechanism that still fill an airbrake report on the third or later try, you can still detect that something is wrong without the hassle of having your logs filled by the attempts.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. With regard to reschedule method, my impression is that it reschedules when a job fails (mine would pass if i am not raising the error.) Am i correct here?